# Ruby string manipulation how to add space?

Tags: ruby

I am having problems string manipulation.

Here is to achieve with my string manipulation:

What I have:

```
<item name="RFSF "Blindspot"" type="project" id="34"/>
```

I want to add a line break just before the "" and it should also gsub all existing white space.

Here is the XML generator:

```
xmlmenu.item(:name=> convert_html_entities(kidsmovies[n].name),  :type=>"project", :id=> kidsmovies[n].id)
```

Example want I want to do:

```
xmlmenu.item(:name=> convert_html_entities(kidsmovies[n].name).gsub(remove all whitespace).gsub(add one whitespace between the words).gsub.(create a linebreak just before ""),  :type=>"project", :id=> kidsmovies[n].id)
```

Comment: Could you please write a full text example of what you want to get at the end? Thanks

Comment: What you have is invalid XML.

Comment: It is just a piece of my code..

Comment: Ok but you show what you have in XML that's good. Why don't you write a sample of how you want it to look like after transformation?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a bad XML, it must be:

```
<item name="RFSF \"Blindspot\"" type="project" id="34"/>
```

then, to cut out extra spaces:

```
string.gsub(/\S+/).map.join(' ')
```

or:

```
string.split(' ').join(' ')
```

But what is `create a linebreak just before ""`?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a helper:

```
def format_name(str)
  html_escape(str.gsub(/\s+/, " ")) + "\n"
end
```

Then use it instead of convert_html_entities, which is not working (because it is not escaping quotes, making the XML output invalid). LIke so:

```
xmlmenu.item(:name=> format_name(kidsmovies[n].name), :type=>"project", :id=> kidsmovies[n].id)
```